# What is the environment variable name in PowerShell for MSBuildExtensionsPath

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-3.0

I've been looking everywhere to see which is the environment variable for the `MSBuildExtensionsPath` that I have in my TFS project file. How do I access this environment variable in PowerShell?

EDIT:
Out of the ones listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx), I am not sure which one I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you access env vars in PowerShell is:

$env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY

That said, I don't see via your link an env var that corresponds to the MSBuild built-in variable `MSBuildExtensionsPath`.  Why don't you pass that variable value into your PowerShell script as a parameter?

Comment: After some thought, I think I will be. I will use an old log file to get that path and I'll just pass it as an argument. Thank you for the example!